# Текст при заполнении блока уходил за левую его часть при перезаполнении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет. Есть ли возможность смены направления переполнения блока? Имеется ввиду, что когда блок заполняется текстом с право на лево (text-align: right) при заполнении блока текст уходил за левую грань блока, а не за правую. direction: rtl; решает эту проблему, но появляется новая: при наборе теста слова тоже меняют направление, что не нужно.

upd: как оказалось, достаточно было просто выставить min-width, вместо width блоку output

Comment: Примеры покажите пожалуйста, желательно мини-пример. Который симулирует вашу проблему.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Craith777/2nbd7qt3/22/ вот пример. На нем видно, что перезаполнение уходит в правую часть, хотелось бы наоборот, чтобы уходило влево

Answer (score 0):

Используйте css свойство `direction: rtl`

Comment: Я выше писал, что это решение имеет нежелательный побочный эффект, по этому от него пришлось отказаться